# Does anyone know where the SQL Server Connection Properties are stored?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, central-management-server

When you add a Server Instance to Central Management Servers or even your local instance of SSMS, if you click on the connection properties tab you can select the default database you'd like to connect to as well as network protocols connection and execution time-outs and even a custom color for the taskbar when you open a query to using the connection you're defining.

This allows you to shutdown SSMS on your machine and come back days/weeks/years later and connect to a previously connected server and have these connection properties already populated.

This information has to be stored in table in one of the four default databases, but I have been unable to locate any of this information.  I'm particularly interested in the fields that define the custom color of the taskbar for a connection.

I'm working on re-organizing my company's CMS and would like to organize by tier/environment and color code each one differently.

So all

- production servers would be red,
- Beta/Stage would be Orange,
- QA would be green,
- Dev would be blue.

I have already crafted a query to insert each Server Instance from a table into CMS, but can't seem to figure out how to populate the default connection's color.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I suspect this is stored on a file on your local machine rather than a database.

Comment: @MartinSmith is correct  [The color settings are not saved in the central management server, they are persisted on the computer where SSMS runs.](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/534283/connection-properties-are-not-retained-when-servers-are-registered-under-a-central-management-server) and [brent talks a bit about it here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/74253/8783)

Comment: Has to be stored in table in one of the four default databases?   If you go to SSMS on another machine are they persisted?   Would you even want the same protocol and default database across different client machines?

Answer (score 1):

The list of the servers are kept in the `msdb` database.

```
SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysmanagement_shared_registered_servers
```

If you're wanting the connections and tabs to be the same, then you would need to go to Tools --> Import and Export Settings... and export the selected environment settings. 
The two that would work for what you're asking for is under Options --> Environment. The two options would be "General" and "Tabs and Windows". It will export to a file. Send that to whomever will need it, and they can import it.